# GitHub codespace forwarded port local address not correct

Tags: vscode-devcontainer, codespaces, github-codespaces, devcontainer

I have a docker compose setup that I have configured to be able to deploy to Codespaces. However when when setup completes, the URL for the forwarded port creates a download response instead of taking me to the web server. However, when access the URL with 'preview' in the link, it works correctly.

Codespace local address URL: https://refactored-spoon-jqj97wvp4qcqv4g-80.app.github.dev/ [Causes a download response and does not work]

URL that does work: https://refactored-spoon-jqj97wvp4qcqv4g-80.preview.app.github.dev/

Link to repository: https://github.com/DeschutesDesignGroupLLC/wordpress-plugin-template/tree/master/.devcontainer

Why does the automatic port forward URL that is setup not contain 'preview' in the address?